# Youtube dl how to download all playlist devided into different foledrs?

Tags: youtube-dl

In Youtube-dl, i need path for download one playlist with one folder for one different video! and every video need to start name with his number (1 for first and his name; 8 for eighth and his name... )

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Downloading playlist...(results.log)"
youtube-dl -j --flat-playlist "$1" | jq -r '.id' | sed 's_^_https://youtu.be/_' > results.log
num=1
total="$(wc -l < results.log)"
echo "Total videos: $total"
while [ "$num" -le "$total" ]; do
   echo "Processing video #$num Thank you for Patience"
   url="$(sed -n "$num"p results.log)"
   title=$(youtube-dl -f mp4 -o '%(id)s.%(ext)s' --print-json --no-warnings "$url" | jq -r .title)
   echo "Title is $title"
   title="$num. $title"
   fly='"'
   title=$fly"$title"$fly
   echo "New title is $title"
   echo "URL is $url"
   sleep 5
   file_name="$(youtube-dl --get-filename --simulate $url)"
   ext="${file_name##*.}"
   echo "ext is $ext"
   youtube-dl -f best --output  $num.$ext $url
   sleep 5
   mkdir "$title"
   mv $num.$ext ./"$title"
   echo "please wait"
   sleep 1 
   num=$(( num+1 ))
done
#some Housekeeping !!
for i in *; do  mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's/"/ /'`" 2>/dev/null; done
for i in *; do  mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's/"/ /'`" 2>/dev/null; done
for i in *; do  mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's/  / /'`" 2>/dev/null; done
```

- [Get YouTube title while video downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47096751/get-youtube-video-title-while-video-downloading)
- [How do I download with youtube-dl to get video title as filename](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948516/how-do-i-download-with-youtube-dl-to-get-video-title-as-filename)
- [Comparison Ops (tldp.org)](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

Comment: Pass your playlist as a argument to this, preferably in quotes)".

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Download playlist
youtube-dl -j --flat-playlist "https://<yourYoutubePlaylist>" | jq -r '.id' | sed 's_^_https://youtu.be/_' > result.log
#set video count=1    
num=1
total="$(wc -l result.log)"
while ( $num -le $total)
do
url="$(sed -n "$num"p result.log)"
#%(title)s should give video title
youtube-dl -f 18 --output  $num_"%(title)s.%(ext)s" $url
```

References:-
1.radiolondra:
https://superuser.com/questions/1341684/youtube-dl-how-download-only-the-playlist-not-the-files-therein
2.maythux:
[How to specify a filename while extracting audio using youtube-dl?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630134/how-to-specify-a-filename-while-extracting-audio-using-youtube-dl)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)